# Scrollable image in SVG

Tags: svg

I am trying to replicate this HTML in an SVG:

```
<div>
   <img src="tallimg.jpg">
</div>

div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 10%;
  height: 50%;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

So far I have something like this:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-path">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="400"></rect>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <image x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="auto" xlink:href="tallimg.jpg" clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
</svg>
```

This *almost* works but the image is the wrong size because `height="auto"` isn't supported in SVG. Instead it interprets `auto` as `0`. If I use `height="100%" width="100%"` instead, it is scaled to fit inside its container.

Is it possible to do this with pure SVG? Would I be better off layering the HTML equivalent over the top of the SVG?

Comment: What's the expected result? I may be wrong but IMO `overflow:hidden` won't have effect if the container have no `height` set. Also, I'm pretty sure that you're looking for [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio), and that you're not the first one in here to do so.

Comment: I'm trying to create a kind of iframe-like scrollable pane. I'm using it in two places. In both I want the image to be full width. In one I want it to be scrollable and in the other I want it to be stuck to the top. You're right about the overflow container not having dimensions - i've updated my code.

Comment: You're right, the preserveAspectRatio parameter is helpful. Specifically `"xMaxYMin slice"`. I was under the impression that preserveAspectRatio was for the `<svg>` element only. I didn't realise that you could use it on others. Even so, I think I'm going to go with the laying HTML over the top method as it looks to be a hassle to make it do what I want.

Comment: for the overflowed part, have a look to [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) element